# Reexporting methods in AssemblyScript

Tags: nearprotocol

So I have two files, index.ts and storage.ts. There are some export methods in storage.ts that I export in index.ts via "export * from '/storage'" but still the smart contract gives this error.

```
TypedError: Querying [object Object] failed: wasm execution failed with error: FunctionCallError(MethodResolveError(MethodInvalidSignature)).
```

Comment: can you add a link to your repository here please?

Comment: https://github.com/curaOS/source/pull/151

Comment: can you specify which methods are failing ... or even better ... add some steps to repeat the error that you are seeing.  here is a transaction that successfully initializes the contract without error.  https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/Bpw7pYCv2jns4xNceXCAR6kB5mccw2TwCGs2aueEZiBJ